# What does 'take in' mean here?

Tags: meaning

What does 'take in' mean here?

> Overall, soil releases about nine times more carbon than human-caused
>   activities. But that is part of a natural cycle: The amount of carbon
>   released into the air is about equal to the carbon oceans and plants
>   **take in**.

Comment: [*take in*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take-in) #7

Comment: Maybe you've already checked a dictionary, but, at the very least, you should tell us that you did and explain why you were unable to get an answer. Knowing which dictionaries you checked also helps. Moreover, we expect [links to the original text](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/study-warmer-soil-releasing-more-carbon/4512877.html), so that people trying to answer your question can get more context if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In this context **take in** means [**adsorb**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/adsorb).

> The amount of carbon released into the air is about equal to the
>   [amount of] carbon oceans and plants **adsorb** [from the air].